# How to remove an associated item from a list?

Tags: python, list

How can I remove an element from valid_list which has 6 items if it doesn't exist in the jpg_list?

In this case, valid_list has the string 'F' that doesn't exist in the jpg_list. So, I need to eliminate it.

```
valid_list  = ['A','B','C', 'F', 'D', 'E']

jpg_list = ['A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\A.jpg',
 'A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\B.jpg',
 'A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\C.jpg',
 'A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\D.jpg',
 'A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\E.jpg']

def test(): 
    new_list = []
    for val, tweet in enumerate(valid_list):
        if tweet + '.jpg' in jpg_list[val]:
            new_list.append(tweet)
            # I tried 'continue' but It seems incorrect to use it here!
            # continue 


        else:
            valid_list.pop(val)    
    return new_list

a = test()
print(a)

# this code gives me: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E']
```

**The desired output:**

`['A','B','C', 'D' 'E']`

Comment: You forgot to separate `D`, and `E` by comma in `valid_list`, you have `'D' 'E'` instead of `'D', 'E'`

Comment: @ThePyGuy Yeah, but this was my mistake when I copied this example, it doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: Okay, I thought the behavior was different because of that typo.

Comment: Never pop from a list you are iterating. And anyway the good list is saved in `new_list` so why do you need to pop from the original?

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate "d" and "E".
Also with your code, It will not print out "D" cause "F.jpg" not in the list it will go next.

```
 valid_list  = ['A','B','C', 'F', 'D', 'E']

jpg_list = ['A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\A.jpg',
 'A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\B.jpg',
 'A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\C.jpg',
 'A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\D.jpg',
 'A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\E.jpg']

def test():
    new_list = []
    for i in jpg_list:
        for j in valid_list:
            if j + ".jpg" in i:
                new_list.append(j)
                break

    return new_list

a = test()
print(a)
```

Comment: thanks. That works but what is the idea behind iterating over jpg_list first as opposed to my example where I iterated over valid_list?

Comment: it will loop jpg_list firstly and check if  "A.jpg" or "B.jpg" or "C.jpg" ... in the string. The code you wrote cannot check between  'A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\D.jpg' and "D.jpg" because of "F.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Better approach would be to just use `rsplit` twice with `maxsplit=1`, first split on `.` to get rid of extension, then split on `\` on the first item after split, then take the last item, and check if it is in `valid_list` or not:

```py
[x for x in (i.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0].rsplit('\\', maxsplit=1)[-1]
             for i in jpg_list) 
if x in valid_list]

#output: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

And if you want to use function instead of comprehension, you can convert the code above to something like this:

```py
def test():
    new_list = []
    for jpg in jpg_list:
        jpg = jpg.rsplit('.', maxsplit=1)[0].rsplit('\\', maxsplit=1)[-1]
        if jpg in valid_list:
            new_list.append(jpg)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new list with only the filename part from `jpg_list` and then check against `valid_list`

```py
valid_list = ["A", "B", "C", "F", "D", "E"]

jpg_list = [
    "A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\A.jpg",
    "A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\B.jpg",
    "A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\C.jpg",
    "A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\D.jpg",
    "A:\\Admin_Version\\py_files\\images\\E.jpg",
]

new_list = [
    letter
    for letter in valid_list
    if letter + ".jpg" in ([x.split("\\")[:-1] for x in jpg_list])
]
```